# Matching two lists and find uninstall string with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, operators

I have a problem with my Script.
I wanted to make a Script which makes a list of software which is found in a specific registry path
and see if this software equals installed software. and if so it should output me the uninstall string.
but right now it does not work as wanted. it never show me the output I wanted even if its similar. As Example i have the Program Git as Branding and in the software I got Git version 2.26.2 but it wont output the uninstall string when I selected git.

My code is:

```ps
$branding = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\DLR\Branding" | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object -expandProperty ProgramName
$software = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName

ForEach ($brandinglist in $branding) {
    $objCombobox.Items.Add("$brandinglist")
}

$objComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged=
{
    $selectme = $objCombobox.SelectedItem
    Write-Host $selectme
    if ("$selectme" -like "*$software*") {
        $uninstall = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall,     HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "$electme" } | Select-Object -Property UninstallString
        Write-Host "$uninstall"
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `Set-StrictMode -version 'latest'` would tell you that there is `$selectme` and `$electme` variables. That looks like a typo, either in your code or in the question.

Comment: Ditto, plus you have created a scriptblock but this is (as far as I can tell) unattached. Use `$objComboBox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({...})`, so the code runs when the index in the combobox changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying the `-like` comparison wrong, in which you compare the selected item to an array of displaynames which doesn't work that way.

Also, there is no reason to get the Uninstall strings and Displaynames using an almost identical code twice.

Try

```
# get a string array of program names
$branding = Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\Software\DLR\Branding' | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProgramName

$regPaths = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
# get an object array of DisplayName and UninstallStrings
$software = Get-ChildItem -Path $regPaths | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object DisplayName, UninstallString

# fill the combobox with the (string array) $branding
$objCombobox.Items.AddRange($branding)

$objComboBox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged ({
    $selectme = $objCombobox.SelectedItem
    Write-Host $selectme
    # get the objects that have a displayname like the selected item and write out the matching Uninstall strings
    $software | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*$selectme*" } | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host $_.UninstallString
    }
})
```

Comment: The way @Theo did it just works perfect!
 I see how it works now. if there is anything else wrong i come back to you.
Thanks

Comment: @Flighty Thanks for the nice feedback. Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark icon to the left.

Comment: I have a bit trouble at the next step.
Actually i wanted to add a remove button which should uninstall the software selected on button click but i kinda stuck. i dont get any errors but the script just shows me a blank line after clicking the button.

Comment: I use a function which will run after click the button.

function delete {
If ($uninstall){
 $uninst = $uninstall
      & cmd /c $uninst /quiet /norestart
      }

Comment: forgot to mention... $uninstall = $software | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*$selectme*" } | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host $_.UninstallString

Comment: @Flighty in the Foreach-Object loop, use `$_.UninstallString` to build the command. In my code I don't use variable `$uninstall`

Comment: I just got it to work, i changed the argument a bit.